# single quotation marks in American English

Tags: american-english, quotation-marks

I'm wondering whether the single quotation mark enclosing "unreal" has been misplaced.

> They then took the bag into their kitchen to carefully open it. Inside they found two hamburger wrappers and some half-eaten, decades-old french fries -- that were crispy and brown.

> "We saw the fries and were like, 'This is **unreal.'** How on Earth are these fries still in this bag and how are they preserved so well?! It was wild," Gracie added.

Source: [CNN - old mcdonalds found inside wall](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/04/30/us/old-mcdonalds-found-inside-wall-trnd/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

No, that quotation mark is supposed to be there. Look further in front, you will notice another quotation mark. This single quotation mark is used to describe the speech one said, as a double quotation mark is already bring used.

> "We saw the fries and were like,
>
> *'*
>
> This is unreal.
>
> *'*
>
> How on Earth are these fries still in this bag and how are they preserved so well?! It was wild," Gracie added.

Comment: I suspect that the single quotation mark should have been placed after "so well?!" Note that the part enclosed by single quotes is a description of their reaction upon finding the fries. (Note the present tense.)

Comment: @Apollyon they could have placed the quotation mark after "so well" or "unreal", depending on what they said when they say the fries. (The "so well" part could have been afterwards)

Comment: But the present tense involved determine the placement: Consider "We saw the fries and were like, 'This IS unreal. How on Earth ARE these fries still in this bag and how ARE they preserved so well?!' It was wild," Gracie added.

Comment: The part following "were like" presents the quoted speech in the present tense.

Comment: This *might* be part of this quotation rule: "Commas and periods always go inside the quotation marks in American English; dashes, colons, and semicolons almost always go outside the quotation marks; question marks and exclamation marks sometimes go inside, sometimes stay outside." But otherwise I'm pretty sure they excluded it to place emphasis on the unreal part